# How I can run a telegram bot with the Django project?

Tags: django, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Now, to run the bot through Django, I first use the python manage.py runserver command and then follow the link to launch a view with my bot. Can you tell me if there is an easier way to start my bot automatically when starting a Django project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can use a management command to run your bot with something like

`python manage.py runbot`

All Django context, including DB and settings, will be available

Reference to management command page:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is a little late but you can do the following:

create the bot.py file in the same folder where manage.py is.

inside the bot.py make sure you import the following:

```
import django
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '{Folder where your settings are}.settings'
django.setup()
```

and in order to run you just type python bot.py

Answer (score 1):

One baller way that works with live reloads is to use daphne and the twisted loop.

`pip install daphne`

Next, insert daphne at the top of your installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tg_bot',
    'app',
]
```

Finally, import the the twisted loop from `daphne.server` and run the application in your desired app's ready function in your `apps.py` file. For me, it is inside my `tg` app.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from telegram.ext import Updater
from daphne.server import twisted_loop


class TgConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'tg'

    def ready(self) -> None:
        from .bot import application
        twisted_loop.run_until_complete(application.initialize())
        twisted_loop.create_task(application.start())
        twisted_loop.create_task(Updater.start_polling(application.updater))
```